# XSL: How to replace string AND change attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to achieve changing atrribute value and replace a substring of the element WITH XSL.

XML

```
<...>
   <communication type="telephone">123 456 789 </communication>
   <communication type="telephone">789 (EXT)</communication>
   <communication type="telephone">123 456 789 </communication>
</...>
```

should be

```
<...>
   <communication type="telephone">123 456 789 </communication>
   <communication type="ext">789</communication>
   <communication type="telephone">123 456 789 </communication>
</...>
```

XSL (2.0)

```
<xsl:template match="communication[@type='telephone'][contains(text(),'(EXT)')]">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '(EXT)', '')"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="extension">true</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
```

Saxxon states
"an attribute node cannot be created after a child of the containing element"

I didn't achieve to change the value of attribute type, so i created a new attribute. But even with this workaround i have no idea how to make both requirements (add attribute AND remove substring) to work.

Any idea solving this is highly appreciated!

Comment: Your title says "*change attribute value*" and your output shows that you want to change the value of the `type`attribute from "telephone" to "ext". But your code is adding a new `extension` attribute. Which is correct?

Comment: Sorry for this. I meant to add another attribute "extension" with same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want

```
<xsl:template match="communication[@type = 'telephone' and contains(., '(EXT)')]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="extension">true</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '(EXT)', '')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

This part:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(., '(EXT)', '')"/>
```

creates a text node that is a child of `communication`. Once you have done that, you can no longer create attributes of `communication`. You have two instructions that try to do that:

```
<xsl:attribute name="extension">true</xsl:attribute>
```

and:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
```

(the `@*`) part.

The `xsl:attribute` instruction must come first - and you really don't want to use the `xsl:apply-templates` instruction here, since you have already created all the content yourself.

Note also that your `replace()` will not replace the parentheses.

Of course, you could make it all much simpler by doing just:

```
<xsl:template match="communication[@type='telephone'][contains(text(),'(EXT)')]">
    <communication extension="true">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '\(EXT\)', '')"/>
    </communication>
</xsl:template>
```